# Use application signing to control the execution

Tags: .net, certificate, code-signing, digital-signature, assembly-signing

I have a .NET application (.exe C#) that calls different DLLs (C# DLLs and C++ DLLs) - I have their source code to recompile ...

Now, my goal is to sign my application (exe + dlls) with a
certificate and then do the following:
- If the certificate is not installed in the OS -> the application will not start.
- If the certificate is installed in the OS + a DLL is not signed or
signed with a different certificate (used for the exe) -> The app should crash once that DLL called.

Is it possible to do this? using Code signing in .NET ? if not, what's the goal of signing the application?

Comment: This is not what code signing does.  Its goal is to assure the user that *you* are legit, not the other way around.

Comment: What exactly code signing does? can you explain more? is there any solution to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, signing won't help you prevent execution on average system (there exist settings in policy that tell the system to only load signed executables). Signing is used to certify authorship of the EXE/DLL/etc. and the fact, that it has not been modified by virus or troyan.